# Is there a Javascript support library for html5 file API and upload?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, fileapi

until now I was using flash based [swfupload](http://swfupload.org) and its **swfupload.js** which provides users with callbacks from flash and a possibility to set it up.

I was wondering if there is anything like this for HTML5 File API. I'm asking before I make it from scratch myself. I don't want to reinvent a wheel when there might be a good library out there already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played with this in the past:
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

Seemed reasonable for what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

I use valums file uploader. This uploads using ajax by default and provides a fallback (hidden iframe) if the browser doesn't support ajax uploads.

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

The complete upload widget uses the File API for drag-and-drop support.

Comment: this one is gpl2 though. IMHO - MIT is better

Answer (score 0):

And another one ;-)

http://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/

Answer (score 0):

Plupload:

http://www.plupload.com

Has a total of 6 runtimes.